# Pandas : Executing a function based on the values from two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes as shown below:

```
df1 = 

                        A     B     C      D            
timestamp               
2022-04-08 10:07:00     40    50    NaN    50        
2022-04-08 10:07:01     70    80    80     10        
2022-04-08 10:07:02     200   220   NaN    10         


df2 = 

             A_1       B_1    
                
C            10        10
D            20        10
```

The columns C and D of `df1` are present as an index in `df2`. For every row in `df1`,   values in column A and B are noted as a tuple. For example P1 = (A,B). From the `df2`, for every index, the values in columns A1 and B1 are noted as another tuple. For example P2 = (A1,B1). These tuples are passed to a function as shown below:

```
def func(P1,P2):
    .....
    ans = (using P1 and P2)
    
    return ans
```

The answer from the `func` is updated in `df1` in a different column. The desired operation is explained using the dataframe below:

```
df1 = 

                        A     B     C      D       ans_C                         ans_D      
timestamp               
2022-04-08 10:07:00     40    50    NaN    50     func(P1=(40,50),P2=(10,10))   func(P1=(40,50),p2=(20,10))
2022-04-08 10:07:01     70    80    80     10     func(P1=(70,80),P2=(10,10))   func(P1=(70,80),P2=(20,10)) 
2022-04-08 10:07:02     200   220   NaN    10     func(P1=(200,220),P2=(10,10)) func(P1=(200,220),P2=(20,10))
```

Is there an easier way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you provide the DataFrame constructors (on a phone, difficult to copy)?

Comment: data = [[40,50, 'NaN',50],[70,80, 80,10],[200,220, 'NaN',10]]
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['A','B','C','D'])
    df1.insert(0, 'TimeStamp', pd.to_datetime('now').replace(microsecond=0))
    df1.set_index('TimeStamp')`

Comment: data2 = [['C',10,10],['D',20,10]]
    df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2,columns=['','A_1','B_1'])
    df2.set_index('',inplace=True)

Comment: The question is then, can you vectorize the code? Or must you apply on each combination individually? If the latter, @Shubham's answer is quite good.

Comment: It has to be applied on each combination individually. @Shubham Sharma's code worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one approach:

```
for c in ('C', 'D'):
    P2 = tuple(df2.loc[c])
    df1[f'ans_{c}'] = [func(P1, P2) for P1 in zip(df1['A'], df1['B'])]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def func(P1, P2):
    return sum(P1) + sum(P2)

df1[['ans_C', 'ans_D']] = df1.apply(lambda x: [func((x.A,x.B),(df2.loc[z][y] for y in df2.columns)) for z in df2.index], axis=1, result_type='expand')
print(df1)
```

Output:

```
                       A    B     C   D  ans_C  ans_D
timestamp
2022-04-08 10:07:00   40   50   NaN  50  110.0  120.0
2022-04-08 10:07:01   70   80  80.0  10  170.0  180.0
2022-04-08 10:07:02  200  220   NaN  10  440.0  450.0
```